# Flutter - ошибка: No address associated with hostname

Tags: json, flutter, dart

При запуске выдает ошибку (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7).

Я пытаюсь отправить запрос из сайта с настроенным локальном доменом lararest.my. В браузере хорошо работает json код(приклиплю скриншот внизу).
Локальный сервер Open server. http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories - так тоже не работает.
Когда я отправляю запрос, он показывает какую-то ошибку. Так же в yaml файле прописан - http: ^0.12.1.

```js
//File Repository
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Repository {

  String _baseUrl = 'http://lararest.my/api/categories';

  httpGet(String api) async {
    return await http.get(_baseUrl + "/" + api);
  }

}

    //Slider Code

    import 'package:ecommerce/repository/reposiory.dart';

    class SliderService{
      Repository _repository;
      SliderService(){
        _repository = Repository();
      }

      getSliders() async{
        return await _repository.httpGet('sliders');
      }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере вы кидаете запрос на **localhost**, но сервера скорее всего вы на мобильном устройстве не запускали, как я понимаю. Сервер находится на пк, поэтому у вас есть 2 варианта:

1) Если вы используете эмулятор, то вы можете обращаться к `http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/categories`. По этому адресу вы сможете обращаться к пк, на котором запущен эмулятор.

2) Если вы используете реальный девайс, подключенный через usb, то можете подключаться к серверу на компьютере, используя [инструменты google chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server). В данном случае вы будете так же обращаться на 127.0.0.1, а ваши запросы будут перенаправляться на пк с помощью данного инструмента.

Comment: именно при запуске  на мобильном  выводиться такая ошибка.

Comment: если я на какой то поддомен залю свои файлы , потом оттуда спрашивать запрос , то срабоатает?

Comment: @АкбарСулаймонов ясное дело, что на мобильном запускаете) поэтому и не получается. Сервер у вас на пк, а не на мобилке, поэтому если у вас реальный девайс, вам поможет второй пункт. Если на эмуляторе, то первый. При обращении на 127.0.0.1 телефон обращается сам к себе, а не к пк, поэтому у вас в браузере на пк всё работает.

Comment: @АкбарСулаймонов 3 вариант, настроить ваш роутер чтобы он видел ваш сервер. Обычно после такой настройки ваш сервер виден по ip: 192.168.x.x

Comment: я щас попробую на какой нибудь хостинг залить файлы laravel , чтобы через реальный сервер читались файлы, этот вариант считаю лучшим

Comment: файлы laravel залил на реальный хостинг http://flat.imruz.com/api/categories - вот по этой ссылке, все работает , но из fluttera не читает

Comment: Вот такая ошибка выводиться в консоле - Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character

Comment: @АкбарСулаймонов дополните вопрос всем текстом ошибки и обновленным кодом, я гляну

Comment: @maxgmer ,я залил часть api(laravel) на реальный хостинг , вот ссылка -  http://flat.imruz.com/api/categories. При запуске на эмулятор выводиться ошибка ([ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (11051): <!DOCTYPE html>
E/flutter (11051): ^)

Comment: @Maxgmer вот ссылка на полную ошибку - http://joxi.ru/MAjZjGRUxgXXlA

Comment: @АкбарСулаймонов код не менялся? Я попробовал http://flat.imruz.com/api/categories/sliders, в браузере не работает, возвращает то же самое, что и ваш эмулятор, то есть что-то с сайтом.

Comment: @Maxgmer ошибочка вышла, я перепутал с ссылкой , flat.imruz.com/api/ - вот главная ссылка. flat.imruz.com/api/categories